# DiffUtil espresso Test

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-recyclerview, android-espresso, android-diffutils

[Testing] How can we write a test case for DiffUtil?

```
val oldList = listOf("a", "b", 0)
val newList = listOf("a", "c", 0, 1)
```

How can we write a particular test case that our `onBindViewHolder` has not been called for the items in the new list which are unmodified with respect to the oldList, which is basically what `DiffUtil` do to make everything smooth?

Any idea on how can we listen for changes to the recycler view itself?

I am thinking to use `registerAdapterDataObserver(AdapterDataObserver)`, where we can override `onItemRangeChanged` and listen to the changes, but using such an approach in Testing is not good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DiffUtil does not rebind any same item again, so according to the requirement, if this test case run with any other implementation other than DiffUtil, it will fail.

```
  @Test
  fun testAdapter_noRebinding() {

    val adapter = getAdapterObject()

    lateinit var dataObserver: RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver
    var doesRebind = false

    val oldList = listOf("a", "b", 0)
    val newList = listOf("a", "b", 0)

    ActivityScenario.launch(AdapterActivity::class.java).use { scenario ->

      scenario.onActivity { activity ->
        dataObserver = object: RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver(){
          override fun onChanged() {
            doesRebind = true
          }

          override fun onItemRangeInserted(positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int) {
            assertThat(positionStart).isEqualTo(0)
            assertThat(itemCount).isEqualTo(3)
          }

          override fun onItemRangeChanged(positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int) {
            doesRebind = true
          }

          override fun onItemRangeChanged(positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int, payload: Any?) {
            doesRebind = true
          }
        }
        adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(dataObserver)
      }

      scenario.onActivity { activity ->
        val liveData = getList(activity)
        liveData.value = oldList
      }

      scenario.onActivity { activity ->
        val liveData = getList(activity)
        liveData.value = newList
      }

      scenario.onActivity { activity ->
        assertThat(doesRebind).isEqualTo(false)
        adapter.unregisterAdapterDataObserver(dataObserver)
      }
    }
  }
```

#### Update

Added test cases using Mockito, but these test cases are only passing on robolectric not on espresso

```
 @Test
  fun testBindableAdapter_incomingSameData_noRebindingShouldHappen() {
    val adapter = createMultiViewTypeNoDataBindingBindableAdapter()
    BindableAdapterTestFragmentPresenter.testBindableAdapter = adapter

    val oldList = listOf(STR_VALUE_1, STR_VALUE_0, INT_VALUE_1).toMutableList()
    val newList = listOf(STR_VALUE_1, STR_VALUE_0, INT_VALUE_1).toMutableList()

    val fakeObserver = mock(RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver::class.java)

    ActivityScenario.launch(BindableAdapterTestActivity::class.java).use { scenario ->
      scenario.onActivity { activity ->
        adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(fakeObserver)
        val liveData = getRecyclerViewListLiveData(activity)
        liveData.value = oldList
        verify(fakeObserver, times(1)).onItemRangeInserted(0, 3)
        val liveDataNew = getRecyclerViewListLiveData(activity)
        liveDataNew.value = newList
        verify(fakeObserver, never()).onChanged()
        adapter.unregisterAdapterDataObserver(fakeObserver)
      }
    }
  }

  @Test
  fun testBindableAdapter_removeOneItem_verifyChangeOnlyOneItem() {
    val adapter = createMultiViewTypeNoDataBindingBindableAdapter()
    BindableAdapterTestFragmentPresenter.testBindableAdapter = adapter

    val oldList = listOf(STR_VALUE_1, STR_VALUE_1, INT_VALUE_1).toMutableList()
    val newList = listOf(STR_VALUE_1, INT_VALUE_1).toMutableList()

    val fakeObserver = mock(RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver::class.java)

    ActivityScenario.launch(BindableAdapterTestActivity::class.java).use { scenario ->
      scenario.onActivity { activity ->
        adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(fakeObserver)
        val liveData = getRecyclerViewListLiveData(activity)
        liveData.value = oldList
        val liveDataNew = getRecyclerViewListLiveData(activity)
        liveDataNew.value = newList
        verify(fakeObserver, times(1)).onItemRangeRemoved(0, 1)
        adapter.unregisterAdapterDataObserver(fakeObserver)
      }
    }
  }

  @Test
  fun testBindableAdapter_insertOneItem_verifyChangeOnlyOneItem() {
    val adapter = createMultiViewTypeNoDataBindingBindableAdapter()
    BindableAdapterTestFragmentPresenter.testBindableAdapter = adapter

    val oldList = listOf(STR_VALUE_1, INT_VALUE_1).toMutableList()
    val newList = listOf(STR_VALUE_1, STR_VALUE_1, INT_VALUE_1).toMutableList()

    val fakeObserver = mock(RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver::class.java)

    ActivityScenario.launch(BindableAdapterTestActivity::class.java).use { scenario ->
      scenario.onActivity { activity ->
        adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(fakeObserver)
        val liveData = getRecyclerViewListLiveData(activity)
        liveData.value = oldList
        val liveDataNew = getRecyclerViewListLiveData(activity)
        liveDataNew.value = newList
        verify(fakeObserver, times(1)).onItemRangeInserted(0, 1)
        adapter.unregisterAdapterDataObserver(fakeObserver)
      }
    }
  }

  @Test
  fun testBindableAdapter_moveOneItem_verifyNoRecreatingWholeList() {
    val adapter = createMultiViewTypeNoDataBindingBindableAdapter()
    BindableAdapterTestFragmentPresenter.testBindableAdapter = adapter

    val oldList = listOf(STR_VALUE_1, STR_VALUE_0, INT_VALUE_1).toMutableList()
    val newList = listOf(INT_VALUE_1, STR_VALUE_0, STR_VALUE_1).toMutableList()

    val fakeObserver = mock(RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver::class.java)

    ActivityScenario.launch(BindableAdapterTestActivity::class.java).use { scenario ->
      scenario.onActivity { activity ->
        adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(fakeObserver)
        val liveData = getRecyclerViewListLiveData(activity)
        liveData.value = oldList
        val liveDataNew = getRecyclerViewListLiveData(activity)
        liveDataNew.value = newList
        verify(fakeObserver, times(1)).onItemRangeChanged(2, 1, null)
        verify(fakeObserver, times(1)).onItemRangeChanged(0, 1, null)
        adapter.unregisterAdapterDataObserver(fakeObserver)
      }
    }
  }

  @Test
  fun testBindableAdapter_updateOneItemContent_verifyOneItemUpdated() {
    val adapter = createMultiViewTypeNoDataBindingBindableAdapter()
    BindableAdapterTestFragmentPresenter.testBindableAdapter = adapter

    val oldList = listOf(STR_VALUE_1, STR_VALUE_0, INT_VALUE_1).toMutableList()
    val newList = listOf(STR_VALUE_1, STR_VALUE_1, INT_VALUE_1).toMutableList()

    val fakeObserver = mock(RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver::class.java)

    ActivityScenario.launch(BindableAdapterTestActivity::class.java).use { scenario ->
      scenario.onActivity { activity ->

        adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(fakeObserver)
        val liveData = getRecyclerViewListLiveData(activity)
        liveData.value = oldList
        val liveDataNew = getRecyclerViewListLiveData(activity)
        liveDataNew.value = newList
        verify(fakeObserver, times(1)).onItemRangeChanged(1, 1, null)
        adapter.unregisterAdapterDataObserver(fakeObserver)
      }
    }
  }
```

#### Error's with espresso

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Wanted but not invoked:
adapterDataObserver.onItemRangeRemoved(0, 1);
-> at org.oppia.app.recyclerview.BindableAdapterTest$testBindableAdapter_removeOneItem_verifyChangeOnlyOneItem$$inlined$use$lambda$1.perform(BindableAdapterTest.kt:303)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

---

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Wanted but not invoked:
adapterDataObserver.onItemRangeChanged(
2,
1,
null
);
-> at org.oppia.app.recyclerview.BindableAdapterTest$testBindableAdapter_moveOneItem_verifyNoRecreatingWholeList$$inlined$use$lambda$1.perform(BindableAdapterTest.kt:349)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```